# Is there a way to italicize cpp's methods and fields?

Tags: font-lock, lsp

When I use vscode, I find that CPP's in-class fields are italicized and local variables are normalized, which allows me to easily distinguish between them

[image]

For example, I can clearly tell that `thread` is a field and `no_squash_from_TC` is a local variable as follows

How can I do this in Emacs?

Comment: I am not sure (so I am just guessing), but such customization might be possible after [this commit](https://github.com/joaotavora/eglot/pull/839) gets merged. Also, according to [this discussion](https://github.com/joaotavora/eglot/issues/615), semantic tokens are already supported by lsp-mode.